# Expanding on a C-Shell program and chdir() isn't working properly

Tags: c, shell

My instructor gave us a basic shell in C to expand upon, and I'm currently working on getting the shell to change directories whenever the user enters 'cd [directory]' into the command line. I've gotten it to stop seg faulting, but it won't change directories. Can anyone tell me why it isn't working?

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/* Array holds arguments: args[0] is the command. */
static char *args[512];
pid_t pid;
int command_pipe[2];

#define READ  0
#define WRITE 1


int chdir(const char* path);



static int
command (int input, int first, int last)
{
  int pipettes[2];

  /* Invoke pipe */
  pipe (pipettes);
  pid = fork ();

  if (pid == 0)
    {
      if (first == 1 && last == 0 && input == 0)
    {
      // 1st cmd
      dup2 (pipettes[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
    }
      else if (first == 0 && last == 0 && input != 0)
    {
      // Mid cmd
      dup2 (input, STDIN_FILENO);
      dup2 (pipettes[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
    }
      else
    {
      // Last cmd
      dup2 (input, STDIN_FILENO);
    }

      if (execvp (args[0], args) == -1)
    _exit (EXIT_FAILURE);   // If child fails
    }

  if (input != 0)
    close (input);

  close (pipettes[WRITE]);

  // If last command, nothing more needs to be read
  if (last == 1)
    close (pipettes[READ]);

  return pipettes[READ];
}

static void
cleanup (int n)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    wait (NULL);
}

static int go (char *cmd, int input, int first, int last);
static char line[1024];
static int n = 0;

int
main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  while (1)
    {
      /* Initial Prompt */
      printf ("?> ");
      fflush (NULL);

      /* Read in command */
      if (!fgets (line, 1024, stdin))
    return 0;



      int input = 0;
      int first = 1;

      char *cmd = line;
      char *next = strchr (cmd, '|');   /* Find initial '|' */
      char *also = strchr (cmd, ';');   /* Find initial ';' */
      char *directory = argv[1];

      while (next != NULL)
    {
      /* 'next' points to '|' */
      *next = '\0';
      input = go (cmd, input, first, 0);

      cmd = next + 1;
      next = strchr (cmd, '|'); /* Find next '|' */
      first = 0;
    }

      if(argv[0] == "cd"){
        chdir(directory);
    }

      input = go (cmd, input, first, 1);
      cleanup (n);
      n = 0;
    }
  return 0;
}

static char *
skip_white_space (char *s)
{
  while (isspace (*s))
    ++s;
  return s;
}

static void
parse (char *cmd)
{
  cmd = skip_white_space (cmd);
  char *next = strchr (cmd, ' ');
  int i = 0;

  while (next != NULL)
    {
      next[0] = '\0';
      args[i] = cmd;
      ++i;
      cmd = skip_white_space (next + 1);
      next = strchr (cmd, ' ');
    }

  if (cmd[0] != '\0')
    {
      args[i] = cmd;
      next = strchr (cmd, '\n');
      next[0] = '\0';
      ++i;
    }

  args[i] = NULL;
}


static int
go (char *cmd, int input, int first, int last)
{
  parse (cmd);
  if (args[0] != NULL)
    {
      if (strcmp (args[0], "exit") == 0)
    exit (0);
      n += 1;
      return command (input, first, last);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your immediate problem seems to lie here:

```
if(argv[0] == "cd"){
    chdir(directory);
```

I think you'll find that `argv[0]` is the implementation's representation of your program name, *not* the command you just entered, which is probably in `args`. Or `cmd`. Or somewhere.

Even once you fix that, you shouldn't be using `==` for string comparisons in C. One of the `strcmp` family is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'll take your advice and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok so I edited the if statement in my program. Is this closer to the right answer? `if(strcmp (cmd, "cd")==0){
        chdir(directory);
        }`